# problems using the declaration of char

Tags: turbo-c

[My codes and the errors that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzylG.jpg)

I got this problem with the turbo c++ that every time I'm compiling my codes it just pull some errors which I already tested to online compiler (gdb online compiler).

Comment: Post code and error messages as text

Answer (score 1):

The first error is "Declaration is not allowed here".
The file is .C, not .CPP, so it is probably compiled as C and not as C++. Variable definitions in the middle of the code are only allowed in C++. Just move the definition to the beginning of the function.

The following warnings are "Function should return a value".
If a function is not defined as void (eg. int) it should have a return statement which returns a value of the type of the function.